# Date is one day back

Tags: angular, datepicker, timestamp

I select the date *May 01 1985* in my datepicker and send `dateOfBirth.value` to my server, so that it can be stored in the database.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <label><input #dateOfBirth matInput (blur)="_update('personal', 'dateOfBirth', dateOfBirth.value)" (click)="picker.open()" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate"></label>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="profileFormGroup.get('dateOfBirth').errors">Date is not valid</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Whenever I refresh the page, the selected date should still be visible.

My problem is, I have selected the date *05/01/1985*, but my datepicker shows me *4/30/1985*. Why?

```js
private static _formatDate(timestamp: number): string {
  console.log(timestamp); // Returns 483746400000
  const date = new Date(+timestamp);
  console.log(date.getDay()); // Returns 3 but it should be 1
  return date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(data => {
  this.profileFormGroup.get('dateOfBirth').patchValue(ProfileComponent._formatDate(data.dateOfBirth));
  });
}
```

This is the way how I store the timestamp in my database:

```js
private _update(tableName: string, columnName: string, theValue: any) {
  // Set the correct value of dateOfBirth
  console.log(theValue); // Returns 5/1/1985
  if (columnName === 'dateOfBirth') {
    const splitDate = theValue.split('/');
    const newDate = `${splitDate[2]}/${splitDate[0]}/${splitDate[1]}`;
    theValue = new Date(newDate).getTime();
    console.log(theValue); // Returns 483746400000
  }

  const json = {
      table: tableName,
      column: columnName,
      value: theValue
  };

  this.profileService.update(json).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I have also checked other examples like [this one on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker-example). If you select the date *01/05/2020*, the output will be *2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z*, which is wrong.

Comment: Why do you divide by 1000? If you save that result as an integer, then multiplying it by 1000 later will not restore the original value; a few minutes will be missing and that will move the date to the previous day.

Comment: why are you diving it by 1000 ? can you please provide stalkbliz link ?

Comment: @ConnorsFan okay, now I don't divide it anymore but I still multiple it by 1000. I still get the wrong date. If I remove `* 1000`, I get the error *RangeError: Invalid time value*

Comment: @piyushjain I have updated my question and you see a link to stackblitz. It's not my own code but the problem may be the same.

Comment: You can try `+timestamp`, instead of `timestamp * 1000`, to avoid the exception while keeping the same date/time value.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have tried the same but my function `_formatDate()` still returns *1985-04-30*, which is the wrong date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your locale, the month of May falls within daylight savings time.

Setting a date of 05/01/1985 should come out as `1985-05-01T00:00.000+1:00` if you retain the timezone.

What it looks like is happening is you are extracting the date in UTC. This will convert the date to +0:00, and thus take you into the previous day at `1985-04-30T23:00.000+0.00`.

If you try that Stackblitz the problem is proven - Pick a date before the end of March and after the end of October - these dates work fine as they are not in daylight savings.

your format date function pulls the date out using `.toISOString()`. According to Mozzila (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) this will always return UTC time and you get your date an hour behind, and as this is at midnight, it falls to the previous day.

Since you are only concerned with the date, and the date picker may offset up to 12 hours off each way we can check for this.

A default date is always midnight, so anything ahead of UTC is fine as it will stay the same date. Anything behind UTC would go back up to 12 hours, and into the next day.

In the code, checking for the time zone offset will tell us if we are behind. If so then we want to add hours to the datetime object so that when we use `toISOString` we still get the date picked.

so the function should be as follows:

```
const date = new Date(+timestamp);
const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
if (offset < 0) {
    date.setHours(12,0,0);
}
return date.toISOString().substring(0,10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it out but now the result is *1985-04-01*.

Comment: Updated the answer. The old code relied on our current time zone which is different. It's an awful thing to calculate correctly.

Comment: That works great. Just what I wanted. Thank you so much!!